# accessing a method from function constructor

Tags: javascript

How can the retirementAge method access the value of calculateAge method in the same Person function constructor?

```js
var Person = function(name, job, yearOfBirth) {
  this.name = name;
  this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;
  this.calculateAge = function() {
    console.log(2018 - this.yearOfBirth)
  };
  this.retirementAge = function(el) {
    console.log(66 - this.calculateAge)
  }
}

var john = new Person('John', 'teacher', 1998);
john.retirementAge(john.calculateAge());
```

Comment: You seem to want to pass a value from `calculateAge` to `retirementAge`. However, your `calculateAge` function doesn't ***`return`*** anything. And inside `retirementAge`, you try to access `calculateAge` like it's a value, when it's actually a function...

Answer (score 4):

You need to return a value from `this.calculateAge` if you want to get the value by calling it. When you do that, you can just call the function `this.calculateAge()` and it should work as expected:

```js
let Person = function(name, job, yearOfBirth) {
  this.name = name;
  this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;
  this.calculateAge = function() {
    return 2018 - this.yearOfBirth
  };
  this.retirementAge = function(el) {
    return 66 - this.calculateAge()
  }
}

var john = new Person('John', 'teacher', 1998);
console.log("Age:", john.calculateAge())
console.log("Years to retirement:", john.retirementAge())
```

Answer (score 0):

It can access it, you just forgot the parentheses and return the value.

```
var Person = function(name, job, yearOfBirth) {
  this.name = name
  this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth
  this.calculateAge = function() {
    return 2018 - this.yearOfBirth
  };
  this.retirementAge = function(el) {
    return 66 - this.calculateAge()
  }
}

var john = new Person('John', 'teacher', 1998);
console.log(john.retirementAge(john.calculateAge()))
```